# SMS Status BroadcastReceiver called multiple times

Tags: sms, status

Why do my broadcast receiver called many times?  The code below works well but the delete method is called many times.. Method below is sending message from AWS SQS and detecting SMS status before deleting.. I wonder why the Activity.RESULT_OK is broadcasted many times...

```
void send(String msgbody, String msg_receipients, Intent intent,
        final Context context, final Message message,
        final AmazonSQSClient sqsClient, final String queueUrl) {

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    Intent sent_ = new Intent(SENT);
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, sent_, 0);
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPendingIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

    context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

            if (getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Delete(message, sqsClient, queueUrl);
                    }
                }).start();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message Failed. Error Code: " + getResultCode());
            }

        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    SmsManager smsmgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
    final ArrayList<String> messages = smsmgr.divideMessage(msgbody);
    final int c = messages.size();

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Sending messages to: " + msg_receipients);

        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            final String m = messages.get(i);
            Log.d(TAG, "divided messages: " + m);
            sentPendingIntents.add(i, sentPI);
        }

        smsmgr.sendMultipartTextMessage(msg_receipients, null, messages,
                sentPendingIntents, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "unexpected error", e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this by changing how the way I register the receiver and unregistered it after it is called..

```
void send(String msgbody, String msg_receipients, Intent intent,
        final Context context, final Message message,
        final AmazonSQSClient sqsClient, final String queueUrl) {

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    Intent sent_ = new Intent(SENT);
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, sent_, 0);
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPendingIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

    BroadcastReceiver rcvr = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                if (getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Delete(message, sqsClient, queueUrl);
                        }
                    }).start();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Message Failed. Error Code: "
                            + getResultCode());
                }
            } catch (Exception x) {
                x.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SENT);
    context.registerReceiver(rcvr, filter);
```

Comment: time waster on this one is more then 24hours thinking that need to clear pendingIntent and after clearing Pending still calls multiple times......understood exatly what is the meaning of lifesucks in this example.....Thank you for the solution